# Checkbox validado y mostrar popup

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

les explico, sucede que quiero que cuando se acepte los términos y condiciones, y al darle Entrar, me muestre el pop up integrado en el botón, pero sucede al contrario o en desorden, sin chulear el checkbox o estando chuleado,  si o si me muestra el pop up integrado.

```
<form method="POST" action="">
     <input type="checkbox" name="aceptar" id="aceptar" >
     Acepto terminos y condiciones 
  </form>

   <button id="enviar" type="button" title="gifdpopbox_818182126315709_df0d42dea">
     <span>Entrar</span>
     </button>
```

Y para validar el checkbox con JS tengo lo siguiente :

```
       $(function() { $("#enviar").click(function(event){
    var seleccion = $("#aceptar")[0].checked;
    if(!seleccion){
        event.preventDefault();
        alert("Acepta las condiciones");
    }
});
```

});

La idea es que si no se aceptan los términos no muestre nada, solo va mostrar cuando se aceptan los términos y luego dar clic a Entrar

Gracias

Comment: Ejecutando tu código aparece el Popup cuando presioné Entrar y no estaban marcados los Términos y condiciones. Si deseas lo contrario  quita el "!" de if (!seleccion) -> if (seleccion)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Espero te ayude

```
<form method="POST" action="">
    <input id="check" type="checkbox" name="aceptar" id="aceptar" >
    Acepto terminos y condiciones 
</form>

<button id="enviar" type="button" title="gifdpopbox_818182126315709_df0d42dea" onclick="valida();">
    <span>Entrar</span>
</button>
```

function valida(){

```
var valida = document.getElementById("check").checked;

if(valida==true){
    alert("Acepta las condiciones");
}else{
    alert("no acepta");
}
```

}